# Applying function on multiple dimensions of higher dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a higher dimensional array (3 or greater) which is composed of a series of 2d images. If this array is called `x`, then a 2d image will be represented as `x[0,0,:,:]`. Now what I want to do is apply a function that takes in a 2d image and outputs a scalar, on this higher dimensional array so that I would convert the dimension of the original array to one that is 2 dimensions lower. How would I do such a thing?

In other words, what is the faster numpy way of doing this: `np.array([[f(x[i,j,:,:]) for i in range(x.shape[0])] for j in range(x.shape[1])])` for a list of axes and some function `f` that takes in an array.

I've looked at `numpy.apply_along_axis` but that only acts on a 1d array and the shape must be identical. `numpy.apply_on_axes` also doesn't work since it doesn't reduce the amount of dimensions which are given to the function (it gives my function a 4d array, not a 2d array which I can work with). `numpy.vectorize` doesn't work because it doesn't ever apply on more than one element at once.

Comment: With a `signature` you probably could get `vectorize` to work.  But neither it or `apply...` are performance tools.  As long as your function only works with the 2d array, it has to be called once for each subarray.  Regardless of the iteration method, that repeated call probably dominates the total time.   You have to use something like `numba` or `cython` to compile your function if you want any real speed gains.

Comment: You're right. I got it to work with vectorize with the signature '(a,b)->()', but it gives no substantial improvement to just nested for loops.